# Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/... in commit message

Tags: git, github

We're two engineers working on same github repo. 
Other person creates branch on this repo and submits PR

Below are the steps done

- I do changes locally and directly commit to the repo.
- Last time after merging PR and taking the latest changes to my local repo
- when I did commit new changes, I saw github has this weird message

> Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/userNaame/projectName

please clarify if I did something wrong here and how to avoid this kind of commit message ?

Comment: I don't see any message in the link provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `git pull`, which at least one of you two used, runs two other Git commands for you.  (I'll refer here to "you", but this could be the other engineer, or you two may be taking turns.  Think of "you" as standing for "you all" or "both of you", even though only one of you runs each command at a time.)

The first command that `git pull` runs for you is always `git fetch`.  This obtains commits from another Git repository.  Specifically, it uses the repository you name—or `origin` by default—to find commits that they have that you don't have, presumably because those commits were added to their repository after you ran `git clone`.  Git puts those commits into *your* copy of the repository, so now you have them too.

The *second* command that `git pull` runs is usually `git merge` (you can set it up to run a different second command, but obviously you have not done that).  When `git pull` runs `git merge`, it supplies, as the merge commit's *log message*:

```
Merge branch '<name>' of <url>
```

The `<name>` part is the name of the branch that `git pull` told `git fetch` to get from the other Git.  The `<url>` part is the URL that `git pull` told `git fetch` to contact, to get commits found via the name `<name>`.  So if your branch has `origin/master` set as its *upstream*, your `git pull` has your Git call up the Git at `origin` and get any new commits from that Git's `master`.  Then your `git pull` has your Git *merge* those commits, with the message `Merge branch 'master' of ...`.

At this point, you have *their* (the other Git's) commits *and* your own commits, plus a *merge commit* tying your two sets of commits together.  Assuming you are using your own `master`, this looks something like this:

```
          ●--●--●
         /       \
...--o--o         ●   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          o-----o   <-- origin/master
```

Your commits—the ones you made yourself—are along the top row; the shared commits are at the left middle row; and *their* commits—the ones they made after you cloned—are along the bottom row.  The right-most commit is the new merge commit you just made.  I have marked the commits that *you* have, that they don't, as solid black circles `●`.

You now run `git push origin master` to send your new commits to the Git at `origin`, on GitHub.  This sends the commits that *yo* have that they don't, and then asks GitHub's Git to set *its* `master` to point to the merge commit.  If it does so, your Git remembers this, so that your own diagram now looks like this:

```
          ●--●--●
         /       \
...--o--o         ●   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \       /
          o-----o
```

When someone else runs `git fetch` to the Git on GitHub that holds the other copy, GitHub's Git's `master` will now point to this same final commit, so you'll see `Merge branch 'master' of <url>` as the log message of the tip-most commit of this `master`.

---

When thinking about all this, remember that there are *three* Git repositories involved here now.  There's GitHub's Git, holding a copy of the repository that you update by using `git push`.  There's your co-worker's Git, holding a copy of the repository that your co-worker updates from GitHub, and that your co-worker uses `git push` to send updates *to* GitHub.  And there's your own Git, holding a copy of the repository you got from GitHub, where you use `git push` to send your updates to GitHub.  GitHub's third repository simply acts as the *sharing point*.